# Trying to run a python script from nodeJS and can't figure out the argument list

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, typescript

I have to run a python script from my node project that converts a .csv file to a .txt file.

The command for running the python script on the terminal is

```
python3 csv_to_rdf.py "pathToFile" "date" > "nameOfNewFile.txt"
eg. python3 csv_to_rdf.py modifiedCSV.csv 08122022 > test.txt
```

I am using the `child_process.spawn()` method in nodeJS to run the script but I can't figure out the args.

When I use the following code snippet:

[image]

I get the following error message:

[image]

My question is how do I send in "**> test.txt**" in my `spawn()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incredible, I am a semantic developer, and I had an extremely similar file (a python script that parsed a `.csv` and then converted it to `.txt` and then to `.TriG`) and I needed it run in my Node.js backend.

---

### Short answer

A very simple solution I thought of after writing everything below is:

**Python is better at writing to files than bash.** Use python to write to your file and then do not pass a redirect into your `spawn()` and you'll be good. Escaped characters are difficult to handle in the `child_process` because you have to deal with JavaScript and Python both trying to handle escaped characters at the same time. If python doesn't have write access, then below may server you better.

---

### Long answer

I moved away from child processes because they cause security issues. **Any `child_process` with  user input can be exploited.** If you could move away from a child process and re-write your python file in JS/TypeScript, that would be best. If you are confident in the use of the `spawn`, then here is a solution:

Firstly, you cannot add a redirect to your spawn because the command is `python3` and, as the error suggests, `python3` takes the redirect as an unrecognized argument. It literally takes it as an argument to the python file, so `sys.argv` *is* the array you passed in the `spawn`. Python will take it in but without seeing your python code, I couldn't say how the extra arguments are being handled. Obviously an error is being thrown.

Remember the `child_process.spawn()` happens asynchronously, so the `stdout` and `stderr` can be extracted right after. Read [child_process.spawn() docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options). So remove the redirect in the `spawn`s argument array and just run another `child_process` or use `fn` to write the output to a file when the `stdout` occurs:

```js
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');
const childPython = spawn('python3', ['modifiedCSV.csv', '08182022']);

childPython.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Or you could use `exec` instead.

```js
const { exec } = require('node:child_process');

const path = "modifiedCSV.csv";
const date = "08182022";

exec(`python3 ${path} ${date} > test.txt`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
})
```

The main issue is, if the path to the modified csv file is in anyway connected to a user's input, you have a security risk, because if `python3` is run as `sudo`, which I believe in node, it is, a user can inject python code in-place of the file path and re-write and encrypt all the files that it can touch.

Comment: This is awesome! I did have python write to the file like you mentioned in your short answer but I want the file that is generated to have a different name. Not passing a redirect just creates a file with <currentfilename_date.csv> and I want it to output something like <postedtransactions_20230906.txt>

Comment: @Orbita1frame In Python, you can specify the name of the file when you open it. Pretty easy search to find an answer to naming python files.

Comment: Is there a way to wait for the python script to finish executing before moving onto the next step. I am trying to upload the generated file to s3 but node doesn't wait for the exec command to finish.

Comment: The `exec` command is asynchronous. There is an `execSync` command, but it will make all server execution wait for the python files completion. A better option is to `.then()` the `exec` method or to add an `await` depending if the `exec` function is called in an `async` function. Hope this helps @Orbita1frame! Please keep the dialog going if anything in this comment doesn't make sense.